# Redshift failed COPY is not setting pg_last_copy_id()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have some `COPY` queries that fail due to bad data. My application code needs to call `pg_last_copy_id()` so that it can report these errors.

I'm repeatedly seeing it get `-1` for the last copy ID for some inputs and not others. It's consistent which input files don't get the copy ID set after the query.

This is what [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_LAST_COPY_COUNT.html) say on the subject:

> If the COPY fails because of a syntax error or because of insufficient privileges, the COPY ID is not updated and PG_LAST_COPY_COUNT returns the count for the previous COPY. If no COPY commands were executed in the current session, or if the last COPY failed during loading, PG_LAST_COPY_COUNT returns 0. For more information, see PG_LAST_COPY_ID().

Based on that it seems like it should be getting set - for example, I manually checked `stl_load_errors` and saw this as `err_reason` on line 2:

```
Invalid digit, Value 'N', Pos 0, Type: Integer
```

`pg_last_query_id()` works, but there's some complexity there because I sometimes see another transaction-related query in between the failed COPY and my call to it.

I'm definitely only using one DB session - so why can't I get the copy ID?

Comment: Looking at the docs at [Aws Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_LAST_COPY_ID.html) Page, pg_last_copy_id should return the correct ID.
based on the docs, it should only be set when a copy command is fired. And should essentially remain unchanged untill a new query is fired. 
Could you share a bit of more context/tables/code to better understand the problem.